IBM Rhapsody generated file locations
I'm using Rhapsody to generate C++ code from my model.
I can use the CPP_CG.Configuration.DefaultImplementationDirectory (set to src) and CPP_CG.Configuration.DefaultSpecificationDirectory (set to include) properties of a given Configuration to create a file structure like this:
base_directory
    makefile
    include
       all .h files
    src
       all .cpp files.

I can also use the CPP_CG.Package.GenerateDirectory property of a package to change the directory structure to:
base_directory
    makefile
    Package1
        include
            package 1 .h files
        src
            package 1 .cpp files
    Package2
        include
            package 2 .h files
        src
            package 2 .cpp files

but what I need is this directory structure (to match the existing one from code written not using Rhapsody)
base_directory
    include
        Package1
            Package 1 .h files
        Package2
            Package 2 .h files
    src
        Package1
            Package 1 .cpp files
        Package2
            Package 2 .cpp files

Is there some combination of properties that will get me the directory structure I want?
